# which atom_style to be able to simulate a heating a CNT in water in edpd model?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, vmd

I am trying to use energy conservative dissipative dynamic (edpd) model to simulate heating a flexible CNT which is floating inside a liquid (water). Using create_atoms command I am creating my liquid beads. I used VMD nanotube builder to create the CNT and got the initial CNT data file from VMD using topo tools, so that I can use read_data command in my input file to read the CNT data file.

My question is which atom_style do I define in companion with edpd atom_style to be able to read all the bonds, angles dihedrals and impropers of my CNT? I tried

atome_style hybrid edpd full

but that also gives me " Incorrect atom format in data file " error.

I did use atome_style hybrid edpd bond angle

which does not still support the dihedrals and impropers.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you add your input file and data file with the question?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to attach them here.

Comment: There is no option for attach.

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi if the file is only a few hundred lines long, then just put it in a `code` block.